# Once the thread is yielded, Operating system will switch execution to an idol process?

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

I am new to operating System so I could not understand this concept that

Once the thread is yielded, Operating system will switch execution to an idol process to change the priority of current calling thread. ???
if yes then how if no then how ??????

Comment: `Thou shalt not worship graven idol [processes]`? That's a modern translation, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a thread yields, the operating system might use that core to run any ready-to-run thread (either from the same process or some other process) that it believes should run. It may also switch immediately back to the yielding thread even if there are other ready-to-run threads because doing otherwise might require expensive inter-core synchronization.

The "how" is basically as follows:

1. The OS enters protected mode and calls the scheduler to see if there's another ready-to-run thread.
2. If there is, a context switch takes place and the user context to restore is switched to the context of the new thread and the old thread's context is stored.
3. The kernel switches back to user space, restoring the user context of the thread it wishes to run.

Some OSes have separate pools of ready-to-run threads for each core to avoid the scheduler having "one big lock" that slows down context switches due to inter-core synchronization. Such an OS might not actually yield if all ready-to-run threads are "owned" by other cores, or it might decide that this situation justifies inter-core synchronization and check the other cores to "steal" a ready-to-run thread (or "trade" threads).

Comment: Does it change the priority of current calling thread. ??? by switching execution to an idol process??

Comment: @BilalMaqsood The dynamic priority of the current calling thread might be adjusted upwards to reflect the fact that it voluntarily yielded.